# SMS not working in 4.7.23

Tags: 4.7, civisms

When attempting to send an SMS in 4.7.23 no text area appears in the dialog for entering the message. I DO get the 'From', 'To', 'Name; and 'Template' widgets. If I press send SMS I get the error 'Please provide Text message.'

This was working last time I used it (maybe 4.7.21?)

I have tried this with different browsers and different SMS providers to no effect. The problem arose with v2 of the clickatell extension and upgrading to version 3 made no difference.

Suggestions appreciated

[image: Send SMS Dialog]

Comment: Seems to be related to this error message: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(prefix + "editMessageDetails").style')`

Answer (score 1):

Searched the www directory for files containing 'editMessageDetails' (grep -inr "editmessagedetails" /var/www/) and compared the result for two different civi installations. Faulty installation had many files with this string in templates_c and the tmp directories. Cleared these & problem vanished.

This can be achieved by:

- Clearing the cache via CiviCRM UI - [docs in wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Cleanup+Caches+and+Update+Paths)
- Executing same via CLI, eg `cv api System.flush` (or equivalent `drush`, `wp-cli` commands)
- Manually removing the directories and files beneath `templates_c` (and `tmp`?) directories.

Comment: Bryan - if you 'accept' your own answer it gets a big green tick and keeps SE happy